# Remove stop words from user input C++

Tags: c++

In the function named `removeStopWords` there is one array named `original_words` and there is another named `stop_words`, I want to print all the elements of `original_words` that are not present in `stop_words`

Here is my code, I tried using multiple conditions using a nested loop, but they didn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void removeStopWords(string str);

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"String : ";
    getline(cin, str);
    removeStopWords(str);
    return 0;
}


void removeStopWords(string str)
{
    string stop_words[10] = { "this" , "is " , "a" , "are" , "and" , "as" , "at" , "do" , "hence" , "your"};
    string out[1000] ;
    string original_words[1000] ;
    int length = str.size();
    int BreakWordIndex = 0;
    int index_out = 0;
    string temp;
    int count = 0;

    int number_of_words = 1;
    //loop to counter number of words in the input string
    for(int x = 0; x<length; x++)
    {
        if(str[x] == 32)
        {
            number_of_words++;
        }
    }
    //loop to put all the words of the string in an array
    for ( int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == 32)
        {
            index_out++;
        }
        else
        {
            original_words[index_out] += str[i];//this
            
        }
        
    }
    //tester loop
    for(int i = 0; i<number_of_words; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(original_words[i] != stop_words[j])
            {
                out[i] = original_words[i];
            }
        }
        // out[count] = original_words[i];
    }
    // cout<<count;

    for ( int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<out[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your parameters aren't changed, just copies of them you'll never see after the functions are completed.

Comment: @Mxneeb The function removePunctuationMarks is not used.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am not running that particular function at the moment because I am actually working on the removeStopWords function, and in that function I am having problem

Comment: @Mxneeb you still didn't explain what your specific issue is. _"didn't work"_ isn't a sufficient explanation. Post a [mcve] including all relevant information.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there is one array named original_words and there is another named stop_words, I want to print all the elements of original_words that are not present in stop_words

Comment: @Mxneeb and what did you add regarding _"didn't work"_? I can't spot any improvement, sorry.

Comment: Note your code can be cleaned up quite a bit by using more of the standard library. Example here : https://onlinegdb.com/dI9A2tslL

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the words in the input string to be separated by whitespaces, you could create a vector of words from the input string:

```cpp
std::istringstream iss{ str };  // str is the input string
std::vector<std::string> words{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ iss },
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}
};
```

Then, you could remove the words in `stop_words`. Notice:

1. `stop_words` should be sorted, and
2. `std::erase_if` is only available since C++20.

```cpp
std::erase_if(words, [&stop_words](const std::string& word) {
    return std::ranges::binary_search(stop_words, word); }
);
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/r3n4zsrjj)

---

Things that would require some extra work from here:

- Words in input string may be separated by other delimiters than whitespace (e.g. punctuation marks).
- The search of stop words may need to be case-insensitive.